# Do InternalVisibleTo and the Dynamic Language Runtime not work well together?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, dynamic-language-runtime, internalsvisibleto

I have the following class in a Universal Windows exe project (actual functionality not included).

```
sealed class DataPage
{
    public DataPage(dynamic page)
    {
        Data = page;
    }

    public dynamic Data { get; private set; }
}
```

This assembly includes the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute so I can unit test internal classes:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("PictureFrame.UnitTests")]
```

The unit test project (Universal Windows Unit Test project) compiles just fine. The test below however will throw an exception when passing a `dynamic` object to the `DataPage` constructor. It does not except when the instance passed is of type `object`.

```
[TestMethod]
public void ReproException()
{
    var o = new object();
    var page = new DataPage(o); // this works fine

    var d = (dynamic)o;
    var page1 = new DataPage(d); // this throws exception
}
```

The exception thrown is: `'PictureFrame.Model.DataPage.DataPage(object)' is inaccessible due to its protection level.`

I can of course mark the internal classes public if they interact with dynamic objects but is this something that is expected to work? This is the first time I've used `InternalsVisibleTo` and `dynamic` and am a bit surprised by this behavior, but perhaps it is an edge case from the DLR perspective.

(In real life the dynamic object is an `ExpandoObject` deserialized from json.)

Comment: FYI: this works fine if you're targeting a regular .NET project, once you add `Microsoft.CSharp` to the unit test project references. So this appears to be a problem specific to the universal runtime. I'm too lazy to check, but I'm willing to bet a small amount of money that the code to call the constructor ultimately occurs in a different assembly (to which `InternalsVisibleTo` doesn't apply).

Comment: I added the Microsoft.CSharp nuget package and no joy. Looks like the constructor call is happening within the linq expressions assembly: ''Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Linq.Expressions.dll but was not handled in user code'

Comment: @JeroenMostert you are right. It does work in a vanilla .net project. A look at the callstack from within the above constructor shows some code from  System.Core.dll!System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2<System.Type, object, ConsoleApplication1.DataPage>(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite site, System.Type arg0, object arg1) not linq extensions as in the universal example.

Comment: You could try (but this is really a shot in the dark) `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("System.Core")]`, since that's where the dynamic code generation seems to live.

Comment: None of [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("System.Core")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.CSharp")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("System.Dynamic.Runtime")] do the trick. Oh well. I'll write something up on Microsoft connect and move on.